# Exception handling in flutter + VS Code

Tags: flutter, exception, async-await, try-catch

I have a simple functionality for user authentication. When user clicks `Login` buttonm than callback calls `login` method from `SecurityBloc` which in its turn calls `execute` method of `ApiProvider`.

If user enter wrong password than method `_handleResponse` throws `ApiException` with error description which I am expecting to be catched in method `login` of `SecurityBloc`. And **it works as expected** when I run project under the **web**. I see snackbar with error message.

The problem occurred when I run project under Android. When user enter wrong password than VS Code (I use it) stops on line with `throw ApiException('invalid authentication response');`, i.e. debugger thinks that this exception is unhandled! But it is catched and handled (see code). When I click button `continue` on debugger control panel, the highlighted row jumps over the code and at the end I see the error message in snackbar.

So is it possible to skip (fix) this situation? Maybe is it knowing bug and there is a workaround?

P.S. If I checked off the "Uncaught exception" checkbox looks fine but it is not the case because now I may pass really uncaucht exceptions.

Any ideas?

```dart
class ApiProvider {
  /// Executes HTTP request
  Map<String, dynamic> execute(url, query, ...) async {
    final response = await http.post(url,query:query);
    return _handleResponse(response);
  }

  /// Parses HTTP response
  Map<String, dynamic> _handleResponse(Response response) {
    if (!response.contains('user')) {
      throw ApiException('invalid password');
    }
    ... // other statements
  }
}
```

```dart
class SecurityBloc {
  Future<AuthEvent> login(String user, String password) async {
    try {
      final data = api.execute()
      if (data == null) {
        throw ApiException('invalid authentication response');
      }
      final token = _parseData(data); // Can throws FormatException
      return AuthEvent.ok(token);
    } on ClientException catch(e) {
      return AuthEvent.error(e.message);
    } on FormatException catch(e) {
      return AuthEvent.error(e.message);
    } on ApiException catch(e) {
      return AuthEvent.error(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

```dart
class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final securityBloc = SecutiryBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      ...
      FlatButton(
        child: Text('Login'),
        onPressed: () async {
          final authEvent = await securityBloc.login(...);
          if (authEvent.failed) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackbar(...); // Show authentication error
          } else {
            // access granted
          }
        },
      ),
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3475 that I raised...if you follow the thread and the link at the end it would appear a fix was posted to master in early October....don't know when it will make it through the releases to stable. Basically though, this is an issue that impacts the IDE and won't manifest itself in the released app on a device.

Comment: Did this answer your question?